PHPStorm Добавить go to к классу с динамическим путем
<?php

namespace App\Test2;

class Test2
{
    public function b():void
    {
        $pathToClass = "App\Test1\Test1";
        $class = new $pathToClass();
        $class->a();
    }

    public function c():void
    {
        $tmpWord = "Test1";
        $pathToClass = "App\\$tmpWord\Test1";
        $class = new $pathToClass();
        $class->a();
    }
}

Суть в том, что в методе "b()" при нажатии cmd(mac) или ctrl(win) на вызов метода "a()" phpstorm сразу переносит указатель на Test1->a();
Но если в пути искомого класса есть переменная, как в методе "c()", то штормовский go to не работает.
Есть ли возможность как - то привязать классы с динамическими путями к go to?
